# AVG PER VALUE SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables like this:

table   Client:

```
idcliente
namecliente
```

table   invoice:

```
idinvoice
idclient
```

table   invoiceline:

```
id
idinvoice
quantity
```

How can I get a list of the name of clients that bought more products in quantity than the average of products sell it by each client

Comment: What is your desired output?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: kindly share schema and data set

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

The schema is

```
table client
(idclient -> namecliente )
table invoice
(idinvoice -> idclient(Foreign key client) ) 
table invoiceline
(id -> idinvoice(Foreign key invoice), quantity)
```

And the query I have is:

```
SELECT  client.nameclient
FROM client,invoice, invoiceline
WHERE client.idclient = invoice.idclient
AND invoive.idinvoice = invoiceline.idinvoice
AND (quantity > (select  AVG(quantity) FROM invoiceline))
```